# Why does mount point changes for an external drive

Tags: macos

I have a volume formatted in APNS as toshibe4TB
at some point the drive "jumps" from /Volumes/toshiba4TB to "/Volumes/toshiba4TB 1".

I ejected the drive, reconnected and now it's "/Volumes/toshiba4TB 2"

Any idea what is going on?

That's on ventura 13.4